# remove () from category number

Tags: plugin-development

I have found this code here.

```
$args = array(                 
  'hide_empty' => FALSE,                 
  'title_li'=> __( '' ),                 
  'show_count'=> 1,             
  'echo' => 0
);             
  $links = wp_list_categories($args);
  $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>(', $links);
  $links = str_replace(')', ')</span>', $links);
echo $links;
```

This returns something like this `(5)`.
I want to remove `()` and show only 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make you good to go:

```
$args = array(                 
  'hide_empty' => FALSE,                 
  'title_li'=> __( '' ),                 
  'show_count'=> 1,             
  'echo' => 0
);             

$links = wp_list_categories($args);
$links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span>', $links);
$links = str_replace(')', '</span>', $links);

echo $links;
```

The `(` and `)` were in the code.

And if you only want to show 6 categories replace the `$args` part with:

```
$args = array(                 
  'hide_empty' => FALSE,                 
  'title_li'=> __( '' ),                 
  'show_count'=> 1,             
  'echo' => 0,
  'number' => 6
);
```

Comment: If this answer helped you out, please accept it as an answer to close this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a filter on `wp_list_categories`.

```
function strip_parens_from_list_cat_wpse_104044($list) {
  $pattern = '|\(([0-9]*)\)|';
  return preg_replace($pattern,'$1',$list);
}
add_filter('wp_list_categories','strip_parens_from_list_cat_wpse_104044');
```

Put the function definition-- the part above-- in `functions.php` or a plugin file then use it like:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories','strip_parens_from_list_cat_wpse_104044');
$links = wp_list_categories($args);
remove_filter('wp_list_categories','strip_parens_from_list_cat_wpse_104044');
```

Or if you want this to operate globally, put `add_filter('wp_list_categories','strip_parens_from_list_cat_wpse_104044');` in `functions.php` as well.